# Dynamic display mask that hides the Customer Phone Numbers in the Customers table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CUSTOMERID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
    CITY VARCHAR(100),
    PROVINCE VARCHAR(100),
    POSTALCODE VARCHAR(100),
    PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Customers 
VALUES
(120, 'Henriette', 'Samuel', '120 Kings Cross Lane', 'Marionette', 'QC', 'R5T 6N8', '611-556-9852'),
(121, 'Rosina', 'Strinati', '121 Hopkins Lane', 'Kingston', 'ON', 'U8Y 9L1', '545-556-9866'),
(122, 'Fillipo', 'Candreva', '52 Ferrari Drive', 'Folliero', 'BC', 'Y9K 8K0', '151-456-7855'),
(123, 'Raffaele', 'Spina', '12 Gianni De Luca St', 'Vulcan', 'AB', 'P90 8T3', '611-556-9852'),
(130, 'Tamara', 'Egorova', '6665 Kiseleva Way', 'Seren', 'MN', 'S9E 3R3', '955-556-2223');    

ALTER TABLE Customers
    ADD MaskedPhoneNumber VARCHAR(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL;

UPDATE Customers
SET MaskedPhoneNumber = PHONENUMBER;
   
SELECT 
    CUSTOMERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, PROVINCE, 
    POSTALCODE, MaskedPhoneNumber AS PHONENUMBER 
FROM
    Customers;
```

I am trying to mask the phone number entirely but it is not being masked.

Comment: I have provided my output as image. The code has been added as text. Please check

Comment: Images of code/data isn't helpful, @KINZEE .

Comment: i have removed the image. Thnks for the input.

Comment: You still need to show the outout data, but using tabular markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the role of the user you are using to query the table?

You are using SQL Server. According to Microsoft:

> Administrative users and roles can always view unmasked data via the CONTROL permission, which includes both the ALTER ANY MASK and UNMASK permission. Administrative users or roles such as sysadmin, serveradmin, or db_owner have CONTROL permissions on the database by design, and can view unmasked data.

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking)

I suggest you follow these steps to test:

1. Create a new role + user.
2. Grant only the SELECT permission to that role
3. Login as the new user
4. Query the masked column

Comment: Thanks. I created a new user and got the desired result.

Comment: @KINZEE glad that helps! Please help accept my response as an answer. Thanks man.